# Will Ubuntu work with my laptop?

Tags: drivers, lenovo, ideapad

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Z570. Its specs are:

- Intel Core i5-2410M Processor with Intel Turbo Boost Technology* 2.0(2.30GHz, 3MB Cache)
  RAM 4GB
- Hard Disk 750GB
- Video Graphics    Nvidia Geforce GT 520 M Dedicated GPU 1GB
- Display   15.6’’ Backlit LED HD (1366x768), 16:9 widescreen
- Multimedia Drive Integrated DVD reader/writer or Blu-ray Disc™1 drive
- Wireless Yes
- Bluetooth Yes
- Webcam    Yes
- Ports     4 x USB2.0 ports (1 combo with eSATA), 5-in-1 card reader(SD/SD pro/MMC/MS pro/XD), RJ-45, VGA, internal analog microphone, 1/8” stereo headphone output & microphone input combo jack, HDMI

So my question to you is, Will I be able to successfully install ubuntu with all of my drivers working or will I have problems?
Also which version of ubuntu should i install?
Thank You.

Comment: Yes, as far as i can tell, u can run Ubuntu without any major problems. although i newer had a bluray reader/writer nor have i ever tested one! :(

Comment: As always, it is advisable to test out Ubuntu first by booting a live CD/DVD/USB and selecting the "Try Ubuntu" (or something similar) first.  And if you decide to install Ubuntu, you can always choose to dual-boot with Windows ("Intstall Ubuntu alongside *" during the installation process), so on the rare occasion that Ubuntu does not work you will still be able to use your computer.  In general, the things that Ubuntu (and Linux in general) has problems with are wireless and video, although most vendors (Nvidia) have Linux drivers on their web sites.  Everything else works most of the time.

Comment: Why don't you just try? Come on... we don't have the hardware you have! Then come back with specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PC is more than enough to run Ubuntu (desktop edition for example).

[Here are the Recommended Minimum System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

Ubuntu Desktop Edition

> ```
> 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
> 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
> 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
> VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
> Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
> Internet access is helpful
> ```

For Ubuntu version i recommend **Ubuntu Desktop Edition**

You can download it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Comment: wow thanks a lot for the quick reply, but i also wanted to ask if i should get 12.10 or if i should wait on that until its out of beta?

Comment: @BeastlyPharoah go for beta (its almost release time) and keep updating your system, you will benefit from the new kernel for your hardware support and it will save you a upgrade once it is out.

Comment: I would recommend you to go for stable. Download 12.04 and when 12.10 comes out officialy then simply update. 12.04 will certainly cover all your hardware, so no need to install a non stable distro.

Comment: I guess i will just install the stable version so that i get a feel for ubuntu instead of running into any bugs in the beta version and abondoning it completely.

Comment: I also want to say how incredible this community is. Truly Truly Impressed. Wow. Just WOW.

Comment: Graphics card drivers may need some additional fiddling, particularly if it uses Nvidia Optimus technology. This is not yet officially supported in Linux by Nvidia. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/82105/how-do-i-get-nvidia-drivers-working-on-an-ideapad-z570

Comment: @BeastlyPharoah Just a push for you to go beta: its pretty stable by now and the new kernel has much better support for your CPU. Just saying... :)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu should work without any problem, although some there always is a risk that something will need more attention. The best what you can do is to run Live CD and test if it works how it is desired.

About version it also depends what you want to use it for. For example I use 10.04 as it is stable and I have quite a lot of python code in version supported by 10.04. Probably you will not have so specific requirements, but if you have any it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with wireless, you should have no problems with any of the other devices but you may have an issue with wireless support. Its a problem with linux in general, always remember to test out the version you are going to install by clicking try Ubuntu upon booting the liveCD or LiveImage.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Z570 and have been using it for over a year now. The only thing I have been unable to get to work is the webcam. Though it does respond, it shows VERY dark and I have found no way to make it truly usable.

Wifi might take some tweaking to get full N speeds, but overall it worked out of the box for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

yes, your laptop will definately work just fine with Ubuntu. I have found many problems with 64-bit for netflix and DVD playback. I might be the only one with that problem on 13.04 though